# What is the easiest way to see total helpful flag counts or rankings?

Tags: support, data-explorer, helpful-flags

As of today,  the Marshal badge has been awarded 3485 times.

Is there a ranking of those 3,485 profiles? Their helpful flag totals?

I'm aware you can see the total in each user's profile. I couldn't locate the information in [SEDE].

Comment: They are ranked on when they were awarded: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/76/marshal . Helpful flags is not in SEDE. At best you can rank them by rep or by days it took the user to get that badge. That is about it if you want to stick to SEDE

Comment: Dharman made this site http://flaggers.dharman.net/ to track people with a most helpful flags.

Comment: @rene Is there an existing sede for days to get helpful?

Answer (score 13):

Not officially. But the information is publicly available on all profiles and can be scraped.

I have made a ranking here http://flaggers.dharman.net/ and I update it from time to time.

Answer (score 5):

We don't have a ["flags" table in SEDE and even if that would ever be added it certainly won't contain the userid that raised the flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84308/flag-data-in-the-data-explorer). Sometimes aggregate counts are added to the Users table. This is done for up and downvotes but not for flags.

We have just enough info to make a ranking based on number of days it took a user to earn the badge. The Badge table holds a userid and a Date. The User table has Createtindate. Joining the tables on UserId and then calculating the DateDiff to return the days between two dates allows us to order the result to get a ranking.

Here is the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1646762/marshal-badge-ranking-on-days):

```sql
select rank() over (order by datediff(d, u.creationdate, b.date) asc) [Ranking]
     , b.userid [User Link]
     , datediff(d, u.creationdate, b.date) [Days to earn]
     , u.reputation [Current reputation] 
from badges b
inner join users u on u.id = userid
where b.tagbased = 0
and b.name = 'Marshal'
order by datediff(d, u.creationdate, b.date) asc
```

When run today this is the result:

[image: ranking of users per days]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).